# Mulitpass getting more FPS than mulitview rendering mode for meta quest 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, vulkan, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm getting more fps for multipass rendering mode than multiview. In my profiler EarlyUpdate.XRUpdate takes more percentage in each frame when rendered in multiview compared to multipass. I'm not using any custom shaders as of now using only lit and unlit shader in urp. I'm using Unity 2022.3.2f1 also updated the xr management and oculus plugin.

Tried with mulitpass and mulitview rendering mode and observed fps and how much percentage does EarlyUpdate.XRUpdate cost in each frame. Since multiview renders only once for both eyes. Do I need to modify the builtin shaders or should I write my own custom shaders then add macros to support multiview rendering ?
Theoretically it should cost less computation. Has anyone experienced this? Any insights on whether I need to adjust the shaders or any other settings for better Multiview performance?
Thanks in advance!